# Unit testing for a web service api

Tags: unit-testing, continuous-integration, automated-tests

Let me say firstly that this is more of an academic question and not a question seeking for tool sets or third party products.. It's purpose is to get some insight into the various methods/approaches used by developers when creating unit tests for their apis.

Take one scenario... an api that takes a request object and returns a response object - a relatively simple method definition and one we would all be familiar with.

Now the inner workings of that api involve interactions with an underlying database and other dependent web service apis. In essence; this api serves as an aggregator of sorts and the functioning of this api depends on the existence of a database and the availability of other web services. So it's a relatively complex api with a significant number of possible program flows.

I would imagine that this scenario is not unique; so I'm hoping for some advice on how to approach testing such an api.

Answer (score 1):

This is the scenario in which dependency injection becomes your friend. Before the dependency injection pattern became very popular many people would swap out interface implementations of things like the Data Access Layer, and Web Services which is really where interfaces in the object oriented sense became powerful. That being said I think the [dependency injection wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) does a great job at explaining this. Hope this gets you started.

Answer (score 1):

I take a couple of different approaches:

Smoke tests:

- This is a kind of health check to make sure the service can bring up the various connections, and that you can do something basic, like hit an endpoint successfully.

Integration tests:

- Bring up the service, ideally building database up using migration tool and a set of fixtures or factories. Bonus points if you can build up the stack from scratch using Vagrant or something similar.
- Hit each endpoint with query string permutations and test the responses.
- You can benchmark the endpoints as well, using something like Siege.

Unit tests:

- Mock out all connections to the service, or use dependency injections to replace them with their testable versions, i.e. sqlite, in-memory cache, etc...
- Hit endpoints that do something other than simple CRUD operations.
- Hit endpoints that are conditionally pulling information from different parts of the stack; i.e. a cache, a database, etc., to test that these rules are working.

Everyone has their own preferences, but I generally prefer concentrating on integration tests to test the actual endpoints. The service models and ORM/ODM models that power these endpoints are tested with unit tests. If time isn't a factor, you would unit test everything.